# Adding objects to an array without triggering the pre 'save' hook for each of them

Tags: javascript, mongodb, cryptography, schema, mongoose-schema

I am encountering an issue when adding a password object to an array inside my collection model. The problem arises because every time I add a new password, it triggers the pre 'save' hook on every existing entry. Consequently, the pre 'save' hook attempts to encrypt the already encrypted passwords, rendering them unusable and unrecoverable.

In my `collectionModel.js`, I have defined a password schema with a pre 'save' hook that encrypts the password and login fields:

```
const passwordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    login: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Login required"]
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Password required"]
    },
    commentaire: {
        type: String
    }
});

passwordSchema.pre('save', async function() {
    if (this.isModified('password')) {
        try {
            this.password = encryption.encryptData(this.password);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    }

    if (this.isModified('login')) {
        try {
            this.login = encryption.encryptData(this.login);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    }
});
```

In my `collectionController.js`, when adding a password to a collection, I use the `push` method to append the new password object:

```
const addPasswordToCollection = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const { login, password, commentaire } = req.body;

        const collection = await Collection.findById(id);

        if (!collection) {
            res.status(404);
            throw new Error(`Cannot find any collection with the id: ${id}`);
        }

        collection.passwords.push({
            login,
            password,
            commentaire
        });

        const updatedCollection = await collection.save();

        res.status(200).json({ collection: updatedCollection });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500);
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
});
```

The issue arises when the pre 'save' hook encrypts the already encrypted passwords, leading to a double encryption scenario. As a result, the stored passwords become increasingly unusable with each addition.

Example of the double encryption issue:

First encryption:

```
"login": "ergeibjzfhzifhaahr:freriiuaiu",
"password": "rgeguegouzzofzfguoz:zefzegfzefa"
```

Second encryption:

```
"login": "regozefhzofhouezeo:zegeroguzgrzoeigheroghzoeuhzeofzuoeooief",
"password": "rogeroghegezrouu:zoigerogherouguzofuzoefhapirzejtjegnoerfoe"
```

This cycle continues, leading to repeated encryption issues.

I tried to make a new model for my password schema on a separate file, but that didnt fixed the issue and created a new table that i didnt want, i then tried to make a new array and swap with the old one, but it looked really poor optimised and didnt worked as i wanted. do you have any clue of what is causing that since i'm not supposed to touch the already encrypted passwords and how can i stop that ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Simply, you can add function decrypt before `push`. Another solution, you can change type from `string` to `list` and append each new password to one list, Its will be join by your service